Subquery in case statement not working. returns Else for every line
I have this query with a subquery inside a case statement that's querying the same table.
SELECT 
  type, 
  sender, 
  contract, 
  transaction, 
  ts, 
  case 
      when contract = 'fe39f0499bf040f351f2e0c3f2c1ae81ea612c48' AND sender IN (
           SELECT 
             sender
           FROM table1
           WHERE contract = '1f469d53942358b1754aa314548ee85cec3d2089' 
           AND type = 'ALPHAKEY'
        ) 
      then 'alpha'
      else 'not alpha'
  end as title
FROM table1



My goal is for senders with a line of type = BETAKEY if they also have a line with type = ALPHAKEY they should get the title of alpha in the betakey line. However it returns not alpha for every single line, even those that definetely shouldn't.
Sample data:



ID
type
sender
contract
transaction
UID
ts




6691f530f07490c1abb9b58c
HUNTER
F6A9371313983c9016cF738516Fe8Be8aE968146
0332fce92897679e97620a097aa515f5d7cf4034
64b9719cb5a86f1b72a7d805ac45afd92eff3e4c7f6ecaef31de1eeba69611d1
F51wmg97UvD
1720841520


66e541c36e053429b94031a4
ALPHAKEY
5bc06909f8bf862f448156f1dc052129905f833f
1f469d53942358b1754aa314548ee85cec3d2089
92da1c693747c8e8b46ec7b28e51eb0e75daeb5f6bf5cf354903a33741e13039
LrnrJ18cTHx
1726300611


66e57cf36e053429b940407c
BETAKEY
5bc06909f8bf862f448156f1dc052129905f833f
fe39f0499bf040f351f2e0c3f2c1ae81ea612c48
8a0ad30b6078bede1315184497af034634c117ca6129e16b2a50d3e7bc3531db
ASCyQX4YSQv
1726315763


66a1bfc78ad2b2d38829ea91
ALPHAKEY
DE19e3980C17c7026325DD89E074861105F0a3c1
1f469d53942358b1754aa314548ee85cec3d2089
cf5e3fd4f540fffe60362429f503db0773e255e5e978e7b3ee8ed93784f1b029
51ajT8MXcQ2
1721876423


66d01ec0cbc8d50d57684cf7
BETAKEY
41655f6f1e3f33a5f21b52ed83e23987f7cb9594
fe39f0499bf040f351f2e0c3f2c1ae81ea612c48
3bdb12ea4008d4103f09d5878d1bbb7ec96b821842c984cff6cadd6293582db5
Gq92k9wXMBw
1724915392



Expected result:



type
sender
contract
transaction
ts
NewColumn




HUNTER
F6A9371313983c9016cF738516Fe8Be8aE968146
0332fce92897679e97620a097aa515f5d7cf4034
64b9719cb5a86f1b72a7d805ac45afd92eff3e4c7f6ecaef31de1eeba69611d1
1720841520
not alpha


ALPHAKEY
5bc06909f8bf862f448156f1dc052129905f833f
1f469d53942358b1754aa314548ee85cec3d2089
92da1c693747c8e8b46ec7b28e51eb0e75daeb5f6bf5cf354903a33741e13039
1726300611
not alpha


BETAKEY
5bc06909f8bf862f448156f1dc052129905f833f
fe39f0499bf040f351f2e0c3f2c1ae81ea612c48
8a0ad30b6078bede1315184497af034634c117ca6129e16b2a50d3e7bc3531db
1726315763
alpha


ALPHAKEY
DE19e3980C17c7026325DD89E074861105F0a3c1
1f469d53942358b1754aa314548ee85cec3d2089
cf5e3fd4f540fffe60362429f503db0773e255e5e978e7b3ee8ed93784f1b029
1721876423
not alpha


BETAKEY
41655f6f1e3f33a5f21b52ed83e23987f7cb9594
fe39f0499bf040f351f2e0c3f2c1ae81ea612c48
3bdb12ea4008d4103f09d5878d1bbb7ec96b821842c984cff6cadd6293582db5
1724915392
not alpha



What am I doing wrong?

Of course it returns FALSE for every line, you are filtering OUT everything else except beta key? WHERE contrac = 'xyz' -- BETAKEY contract AND type = 'BETAKEY' remove this where clause from the main query

Also, you don't need a whole subselect in the select statement as you already have all the values from the row. Just use case when contract = 'abc' AND type = 'ALPHAKEY'....

Added some sample data @JonasMetzler

@JorgeCampos You are not understanding. I added some sample data. For senders that have a beta key and an alpha key they should have the value alpha in a new column in the betakey entry

Sorry mate, YOU are not understanding what you are doing. Forget your case statement (change it to select *), your main query is selecting only rows that matches contrac = 'xyz'  AND type = 'BETAKEY' which means that anything else will not be selected, hence your case statement is useless.

@JonasMetzler done

Your issue can still not be reproduced. The query returns the result you expect, see this db<>fiddle

Now that you changed your query, your case is checking for contract = 'abc' but there is NO rows with that value, so yes, it will always return false, the case statement.

@JorgeCampos I guess the abc is just a placeholder and they check for a real contract value that exists. But as shown in the sample fiddle, their query produces exactly the result they expect. @drum See the fiddle I linked in my comment. Modify it to show your issue if you can't solve it and then share the new url. As your question currently stands, your issue can't be replicated as the fiddle proves.

@JonasMetzler Yes I understand that, but they can't expect the placeholder to change dynamically either they add the correct filter or remove the contract = 'whatever'

@JonasMetzler edited to replace the placeholder and added the contract to my case statement I forgot to include previously

Why do you check for two different (hardcoded) contracts in your query? It's clear this doesn't work.  Don't you need a general query without checking contracts that just returns the information if a "alpha row" for that sender exists or not?

@JonasMetzler I'm using "union" on this table to a bunch of other tables. My problem is that each contract has a fee associated with it but betakey is the only with a dynamic fee. If the sender has previously used the alpha contract then the fee is lower otherwise it's higher. I was gonna use the title to run a case statement for that

@drum Is this what you want?: db<>fiddle

Here this is the query you need. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ps69416FeT81F6fT6zx1js/0 note that the sorting is different.

It's working now thanks, everyone. Both of your approaches work

No probs. I will add it as an answer then.

I've changed your approach a little bit so you query would have a better performance.
Here is the solution:

SELECT 
  s.type, 
  s.sender, 
  s.contract, 
  s.transaction, 
  s.ts, 
  case when sdb.sender is not null then 'alpha' else 'not alpha' end as title
FROM sample_data s
   left join (
      SELECT 
             sender
           FROM sample_data
           WHERE contract = '1f469d53942358b1754aa314548ee85cec3d2089' 
           AND type = 'ALPHAKEY'
   ) sdb on s.sender = sdb.sender
       and s.contract = 'fe39f0499bf040f351f2e0c3f2c1ae81ea612c48'

You can check it working here (note sorting is a bit different): https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ps69416FeT81F6fT6zx1js/0

Why the hard-coded contract values? Aren't all BETAKEY contracts also having ALPHAKEY supposed to get 'alpha'?

@jarlh their requirement. discussed on the comments.

OP must be wrong.

@jarlh well I mentioned that as well ¯_(ツ)_/¯ there were a series of edits from his original question

@jarlh Agree, I still think they want this (as mentioned in comments): db<>fiddle. But they edited their question multiple times and wrote both queries work fine (what I don't understand because they are completely different). As they seem to do not know what they want, we can't really write a good answer.

@JonasMetzler I thought about at first, but after their edits it looks like they are looking whether a different sender exists in a different set of rules (specific contract) and you can't do that by using the same row (as I also originally suggested)
